# Inserting rows to tableView using modal popup

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, modalpopup

I'm making a basic fitness app and within it I have a food diary that tracks the food you eat on a daily basis. I have a modal popup (picture below) that shows when you tap "add food". I'm having trouble inserting rows from the modal popup when the button "Save to Food Diary" is pressed. I'm also trying to update the calories label to the current calories the user accumulated throughout the day. Heres the code i have so far:

```
class PopupVC: UIViewController {
var section: Int?
var caloriesLabel = " "

var tableData: [String] = [""]
let foodDiary = FoodDiary()
var caloriesCell = caloriesForDiary()
@IBOutlet weak var foodTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopup2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopUp: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputFood: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputCals: UITextField!

@IBAction func saveToDiary(_ sender: Any) {
    if (inputFood.text?.isEmpty)! || (inputCals.text?.isEmpty)! {
        return
    }

    caloriesLabel = foodDiary.testVariable
    tableData.append(inputFood.text!)
    foodDiary.tableView.beginUpdates()
    foodDiary.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: (tableData.count) - 1, section: section!)], with: .automatic)
    foodDiary.tableView.endUpdates()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)




}
```

[image: modalpopup]

[image: foodDiary]

Basically i'm trying to update my FoodDiaryVC using my PopUpVC, and i'm struggling to pass the data between both controllers to insertRows and to update my calories label. Hope this was explained well enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS approach would be to create a delegate.

```
@protocol AddRowDelegate {
func didAddRow(name : String, calories : String)
}
```

Then your FoodDiaryVC should implement it :

```
@class FoodDiaryVC : UIViewController, AddRowDelegate {
///Your code
}
```

Add a delegate variable to your PopUp Class

```
class PopUpVC : UIVIewController {

    weak var delegate : AddRowDelegate?
}
```

No you have to set the delegate when you show the Popup

`myPopUp.delegate = self`

When the user tap the "Add to diary", just call the delegate

`delegate?.didAddRow(name: "blah", calories : "blah")`

Comment: Sounds good, will try it now! Quick question, Do i keep the insertRows method in my "Save to Diary" function? Or do i use it in my foodDiaryVC?

Comment: All the data stuff should be done in the same place, so in the foodDiaryVC. Your popup should only collect data to create the row, and let your DiaryVC do the stuff

Comment: Thank alot! It worked! I knew the delegate method was the way to go, thanks again!!

Comment: sorry again, but my calories label is still refusing to update. I'm not sure why. Im doing this:  IBAction func saveToDiary(_ sender: Any) {
     
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        delegate?.didAddRow(name: inputFood.text!, calories: inputCals.text!)

Comment: What's inside your didArrRow function ? Is the delegate non-nil ?

Comment: I have the values of the textfields in my DidAddRow function, and im trying to set my calories label to the inputCals.text. I set the delegates aswell and still nothing. You have an idea? @CZ54

Comment: i'm overseas and its tough to find internet, but the main issue is that my calories label in my foodDiaryVC won't update. I implemented everything you said above. I'm not sure if i'm suppose to put the inputFood.text and inputCals.text inside the function. Can you point me towards a link that would be helpful? Sorry again man im doing this through my phone and i dont have access to internet on my laptop to update my code

Comment: I updated my question herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560953/unable-to-update-label-in-uitableviewcell-using-delegate