# Unable to update label in UITableViewCell using Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a food diary in my app that tracks the food that you eat daily, but I'm struggling to update my calories label in my `UITableViewCell`. My app crashes as soon as i press "Save to Food Diary" and the error is the following:

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

Here's the code I have in my `PopUpVC` (`UIViewController` that users get to see to input the `FoodName` and `Calories`)

```
protocol AddRowDelegate {
    func didAddRow(name : String, calories : String)
}

class PopupVC: UIViewController {

var delegate: AddRowDelegate?
var section: Int?
var caloriesLabel = " "

var tableData: [String] = [""]

var caloriesCell = caloriesForDiary()
@IBOutlet weak var foodTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopup2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPopUp: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputFood: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var inputCals: UITextField!

@IBAction func saveToDiary(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.didAddRow(name: inputFood.text!, calories: inputCals.text!)
}
```

Then I pass the inputs from both the food and calories `UItextFields` to my `FoodDiaryVC` :

```
func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String) {        
    cals.calories.text = calories    
    print(name)
    print(calories)
}
```

I added pictures that are showing the error and `ViewController`. I am not sure why it's finding/returning nil? I'm basically just trying to set my calories label equal to the input (or the accumulation of cals throughout the day)

[image: popupVC]

[image: error]

[image: caloriescell]

Comment: sure the cals or calories  object is nill, as @oskar said, make sure the object of those var are created before you access them.

Comment: Its my FoodDiaryVC thats implementing the delegate of the popup @dip

Comment: i removed the previous delegate related comment. please do not take reference with previous comment.

Comment: cals is a reference to my uitableviewcell, i have updated the post with pics of my caloriesforCell. So basically i have cals as cals = caloriesforCell() @vadian

Comment: @thelegendary3 Please do not post screenshots, post code / text.

Comment: Calling `caloriesforCell()` creates a new instance of the class without connected outlets, that causes the crash. You need the actual reference to the class. Btw: class names are supposed to start with a capital letter. It's confusing to read.

Comment: @vadian HAHAHHA WOW!!! I can't believe i didn't connect the outlets! what a rookie mistake!!! thank you soo much!!!! What's the proper way to reference the class?

Comment: @vadian how would i make the actual reference of the class?

Comment: It depends on how the class / cell is related to the table view. Is it static, then use an outlet, is it dynamic, update the data source and reload the table view.

Comment: @vadian i see what you're saying, i didn't know creating a new instance would remove the outlets. I'm still kind of stuck, and i believe the cell would be dynamic since the calories label will change the more food the user inputs.. any helpful links that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Usually a table view has a data source (array). The table view content is displayed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You need to update the item in the data source which corresponds to the cell and call `reloadData` on the table view. Unfortunately your code does not show this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142351/discussion-between-thelegendary3-and-vadian).

Answer (score 1):

Your `cals` or `calories` object is `nil`, causing the crash. You're not including this object in your posted code, but make sure the object is instantiated before you access it.

Comment: I set my cell as let cals = caloriesForDiary() as a class level variable in my FoodDiaryVC. then in the delegate function im grabbing the label as cals.calorieslabel.text. Is this not the right way to go about it?

Comment: can you show the caloriesForDiary Calss (or struct ) ?

Comment: You're not showing what the `caloriesForDiary() ` does so it's impossible to say whats wrong. Either way it's a bad idea to access the cells and their interface elements like this. Instead you should keep a separate model logic and reload the tableview to reflect value changes.

Comment: @dip i have updated my post! caloriesforDiary is my UITableviewcell that has the labels

Comment: ahh , there u are , where is cals variable declared ? seems problem is not that big you are presenting here. please show  clear problem , think your are trying to setting new row on tableview but you are doing from wrong place, if possible upload whole three classes . cell, viewcontroller and popup view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i dont know what thing is causing the crash but i m sure it can be debugged. Do the following steps as i suggest you. Change the method **didAddRow** to

```
func didAddRow(name: String, calories: String) {
   if(calories.characters.count != 0 && cal != nil)   {
      cal.calories.text = calories 
   }
    print(name)
    print(calories)
}
```

If this does not gives you suitable result than try to print the calories and cal in this method. Check the outlets and put break point in this method.

Comment: So since i created a new instance of my UITableViewCell it removes the outlets which is causing the crash. I'm not sure how to make a proper reference to the class so it can have values inside. Any idea?